# How long on average does it take to receive ABRSM grading results?

Tags: abrsm, exam

Recently, my sister took a piano exam, and it has been two weeks now since she did her Grade 2. It seems to be taking a while, and I would like to know how long it takes the results when you enter for the exam through the county council exams. Does anybody have an idea? And also, how will we see the actual results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://gb.abrsm.org/en/exam-booking/results-and-certificates/) on ABRSM's website should give you everything you need to know. There, you'll see a table that shows you when to expect results based off of when she took the exam:

[image]

Underneath the table is a [link](https://onlineforms.abrsm.ac.uk/) on how to view your results when they do come in.